# Why fixed position not working on mobile device?

Tags: html, css

My modal fixed position works well on desktop, but it doesn't work well on mobile devices and I don't understand why.

https://probaka.netlify.app/kiemelt.html

On this page in the first section when a click the images a modal window opening, but when a click on the image on a mobile device then my modal window opens too high, not the top of the viewport.

**My CSS:**

```css
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.modal--open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgba(255, 238, 177, 0.7);
}
@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(5px)) {
  .modal--open {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 238, 177, 0.15);
  }
}
.modal-inner {
  padding: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.modal--open .count-img-box-img {
  width: 60%;
}
```

**My HTML**

```html
<div class="modal"><div class="modal-inner"></div></div>

<div class="count-gallery">
            <figure class="count-img-box">
              <img
                src="/img/nepszavazas/arpad_utca.jpg"
                alt="Árpád utca adatai"
                class="count-img-box-img"
                loading="lazy"
              />
              <figcaption class="caption">Árpád utca</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure class="count-img-box">
              <img
                src="/img/nepszavazas/belso_dulo.jpg"
                alt="Belső dűlő adatai"
                class="count-img-box-img"
                loading="lazy"
              />
              <figcaption class="caption">Belső dűlő</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure class="count-img-box"> </div>
```

```css
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.modal--open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgba(255, 238, 177, 0.7);
}

@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(5px)) {
  .modal--open {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 238, 177, 0.15);
  }
}

.modal-inner {
  padding: 2.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal--open .count-img-box-img {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="count-gallery">
    <figure class="count-img-box">
      <img src="/img/nepszavazas/arpad_utca.jpg" alt="Árpád utca adatai" class="count-img-box-img" loading="lazy" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Árpád utca</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="count-img-box">
      <img src="/img/nepszavazas/belso_dulo.jpg" alt="Belső dűlő adatai" class="count-img-box-img" loading="lazy" />
      <figcaption class="caption">Belső dűlő</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="count-img-box"></figure>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modal is working but is on top of the page. You need to put a scroll event to top of the page when model is fired.

- [`.scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) - if you use jQuery
- [`element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) - if you use vanilla JavaScript